# Use sed with regular expression for space

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I am trying to use `sed` to substitute a string taking into account an whitespace.
Example:

```
Hello          World
```

to be replaced by

```
Hello George
```

I tried:

```
sed -e 's/Hello[:space]+World/Hello George/' ./infile > outFile
```

but it does not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `[:space:]` and not `[:space]`, I think. Also, `[[:space:]]`, otherwise the square brackets will be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/Hello[[:space:]]\+World/Hello George/' ./infile > outFile
```

or

```
sed -e 's/Hello \+World/Hello George/' ./infile > outFile
```

**Note**: In OSX, you'll need

```
sed -E 's/Hello +World/Hello George/' ./infile > outFile
```

Comment: This works.Is there a case I would prefer using `\+` over `[[:space:]]`?Is it available always?

Comment: I think `[[:space:]]` includes tabs as well and maybe a few other, whereas ` ` is just... well... single space. Both should always be available (in sed)

Answer (score 1):

may be you can go with perl:

```
perl -pe 's/Hello\s*World/Hello Goerge/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sed -e 's/Hello\s\+World/Hello George/' ./infile > outFile
```

The code for space is `\s`, same as `\w` would be for word characters.

Comment: Nope, you don't *have* to use that form, the `[:space:]` can be used as well and is better in some cases (unicode, changed locales etc.)

Comment: @alestanis: I have explained above.

Comment: @January you're right about the *have to*. I edited my answer.

Comment: @alestanis: but you have still a problem with the `+`, which, in "standard" sed is interpreted literally (to have a quantifier, you need to use `\+`).